# Parsing a text file to CSV using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, csv

I am completely new to LINQ and I want to learn it's usefulness in parsing text files, instead of using a scripting language such as Perl or Ruby. I have generated a long list delimited by "CR" and "LF" and I would like to create a .CSV file to export to Excel containing only the first three lines. Example:

```
[CR][LF]
      Field: Microsoft.VSTS.Build.FoundIn[CR][LF]
      Name: Found In[CR][LF]
      Type: String[CR][LF]
      Use: Test project[CR][LF]
      Indexed: False[CR][LF]
      Reportable As: dimension[CR][LF]
      Synchronizes Identity Name Changes: False[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
      Field: Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild[CR][LF]
      Name: Integration Build[CR][LF]
      Type: String[CR][LF]
      Use: Test project[CR][LF]
      Indexed: False[CR][LF]
      Reportable As: dimension[CR][LF]
      Synchronizes Identity Name Changes: False[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
```

(the list goes on)

**Desired output:**

```
"Microsoft.VSTS.Build.FoundIn","Found In","String"
"Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild","Integration Build","String"
```

How can I write this in LINQ the simplest way possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just breaking between "sections" on blank lines.  Just go through the lines throwing everything into a separate buffer until you reach a blank line.  When you do, process the items in the buffer, clear it and repeat.  You can't really do this in pure LINQ *simply* or elegantly so don't try to force feed it into it.

```
var buffer = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(pathToFile))
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(line))
    {
        ProcessSection(outputFile, buffer);
        buffer.Clear(); // or create a new one
    }
    else
    {
        buffer.Add(line);
    }
}

static void ProcessSection(StreamWriter outputFile, List<string> buffer)
{
    if (buffer.Count == 0) return;
    var contents = buffer.Take(3)
        .Select(line => String.Format("\"{0}\"", line.Substring(line.IndexOf(": ") + 2)));
    outputFile.WriteLine(String.Join(",", contents));
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about `File.EnumerateLines` - that's pretty neat.

Comment: `System.IO.File` does not contain `EnumerateLines` in .NET 4.0!

Comment: @JFB: Oops, sorry, wrong name.  That should be `ReadLines()`.

Comment: @Lester: Warning, I botched the name of that method.